# shopify_app syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, shopify

**Edit: Debugging has got me further.  Question clarified.**

We have installed Ruby, RubyGems and Rails and have forked the shopify_app project.  We have created a new rails applications and added three items to the Gemfile: `execjs`, `therubyracer` and `shopify_app`.

Running `rails s` in order to start our rails application returns this trace:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/pete-shopify/cart# rails s
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/shopify_app-4.1.0/lib/shopify_app.rb:15:in `require': /var/lib    /gems/1.8/gems/shopify_app-4.1.0/lib/shopify_app/login_protection.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
...rce::UnauthorizedAccess, with: :close_session
                          ^
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/shopify_app-4.1.0/lib/shopify_app.rb:15
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /usr/local/pete-shopify/cart/config/application.rb:7
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

I haven't modified any files since forking from Github.  Lines 1 - 6 of login_protection.rb are as follows:

```
module ShopifyApp::LoginProtection
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        rescue from ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess, with: :close_session
    end
```

I've looked into this and it **seems** that the error is caused by a new-style hash syntax between Ruby 1.8 and 1.9; `key : value` instead of `key => value`.

Running `ruby -v` from the command line returns `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]`.  This would seem to be OK... but I did some debugging, and inside the file `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/shopify_app-4.1.0/lib/shopify_app.rb` (at the top) by putting this:

puts RUBY_VERSION
exit

It printed `1.8.7`.  **Why are `ruby -v` and `RUBY_VERSION` giving me different results?  And am I correct in assuming this is the cause of my problems?

Note: To upgrade Ruby I installed the later version with `apt-get` and then switched to it by using `update-alternatives --config ruby` and selecting option 2 like this:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/pete-shopify/cart# update-alternatives --config ruby
There are 2 choices for the alternative ruby (providing /usr/bin/ruby).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        manual mode
```

Also note: We're PHP/Python developers so this is all new to us!

**Summary:**

**1 - Am I right in determining the cause of the syntax error?**

**2 - Why does `RUBY_VERSION` and `ruby -v` give me different results?**

Answer (score 3):

There could be something related to your permissions.  Try installing ruby 1.9.3 with [rbenv instead](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#section_2).  It'll install everything in your users directory, so you shouldn't have to worry about any permissions goofyness.